# ¿Cómo compruebo si se repite o no un dato ingresado con los datos dentro de un json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Necesito solo comprobar que los datos no se repitan  para luego aprobar un registro.

Uso un `each` para poder recorrer los datos del `json`, dentro de este uso dos `if`, el primero para comprobar de que los datos ingresados son iguales, si es así, que me mande un mensaje diciendo que está ocupada, hasta ahí me funciona bien, ahora en el segundo `if` compruebo que no se repite lo ingresado con lo que está en el `json`, entonces aquí está el problema porque se duplica ya que lee todos los que no se repiten, pero lo único que necesito es que compruebe si 
está disponible la habitación a esa hora si es así que registre.(al final de cada `if` acabo el ciclo con un `return false` para que no se repitiera el alert o el registro pero no funcionó).

esperaba que con un contador dentro del `if` se solucionara lo de los varios registros, pero no funciona si registro la misma habitación que quedó en el ultimo registro.

```
        var hi = $('#txtFecha').val()+" "+$('#comboboxHora').val();
        var h = $('#comboboxHabitacion').val();
        var i=1;


        var Hora_Inicio = new Array();
        var Habitacion = new Array();
        $.getJSON('even.php?accion=fechainicio', function (data) { //getJSON
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        Hora_Inicio.push(val.Hora_Inicio);
        Habitacion.push(val.Habitacion);


                    if (val.Hora_Inicio == hi && val.Habitacion == h) {
                    alert("La habitacion ya ha sido reservada a esa hora, seleccione otra hora");
                    return false;
                        }

                        if (val.Hora_Inicio !== hi && val.Habitacion !== h) {

                        if (i==data.length) {
                    recolectarDatos();
                    EnviarInfo('agregar', nuevoEven);
                        return false;
                        }

                    }
                    i++;

        })


        });//fin getJSON
```

No sé si sea útil pero dejaré lo que tengo en el `json`

```
[{"Hora_Inicio":"2018-08-30 17:00:00","Habitacion":"Habitacion 1"},{"Hora_Inicio":"2018-08-27 12:00:00","Habitacion":"Habitacion 1"},{"Hora_Inicio":"2018-08-31 13:00:00","Habitacion":"Habitacion 2"},{"Hora_Inicio":"2018-08-29 13:00:00","Habitacion":"Habitacion 1"},{"Hora_Inicio":"2018-08-29 08:00:00","Habitacion":"Habitacion"}]
```

dejo aquí el resto del codigo (calendar.php) uso fullcalendar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='css/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/es.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col-7"><div id="CalendarioReserva"></div></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#CalendarioReserva').fullCalendar({
                header:{
                left:'today,prev,next, Boton',
                center:'title',
                right:'month, agendaDay',

            },
            customButtons:{
                Boton:{
                    text:"Hacer reserva",
                    click:function(){
                        $("#ventanaModal").modal();

                    }
                }
            },

            events:'even.php',



            dayClick:function(date,jsEvent,view){

                if (view.name == 'month') 
                {
                  $('#CalendarioReserva').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
                  $('#CalendarioReserva').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
                }
                $("#txtFecha").val(date.format());
                $("#ventanaModal").modal();
                }
            },
            eventLimit: true, // for all non-agenda views
             views: {
            agenda: {
            eventLimit: 6 // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
            }
  }




        });
    });



</script>
<!-- Ventana Modal Reservar -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ventanaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ventanaModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Reservar sala</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div id="descrocionEvento"></div>

        Fecha : <input type="date" name="txtFecha" id="txtFecha"><br/>

        Hora : <SELECT name="comboboxHora" id="comboboxHora"> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 function cargar_horas()
        {
            var array = ["08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00",
             "11:00:00","12:00:00","13:00:00","14:00:00","15:00:00","16:00:00","17:00:00"];//Horas disponibles 
            for(var i in array)
            { 
                document.getElementById("comboboxHora").innerHTML += "<option value='"+array[i]+"'>"+array[i]+"</option>"; 

            }
            }
            cargar_horas();

            </script>
        </SELECT>

        Sala : <SELECT name="comboboxHabitacion" id="comboboxHabitacion"> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 function cargar_salas()
        {
            var array = ["Habitacion 1","Habitacion 2","Habitacion"];//Salas disponibles 
            for(var i in array)
            { 
                document.getElementById("comboboxHabitacion").innerHTML += "<option value='"+array[i]+"'>"+array[i]+"</option>"; 

            }
            }
            cargar_salas();

            </script>
            </SELECT>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" id="btnReservar" class="btn btn-primary">Reservar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var nuevoEven;
    $('#btnReservar').click(function(){     

             var hi = $('#txtFecha').val()+" "+$('#comboboxHora').val();
            var h = $('#comboboxHabitacion').val();
            var i=1;


            var Hora_Inicio = new Array();
            var Habitacion = new Array();
            $.getJSON('even.php?accion=fechainicio', function (data) { //getJSON
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            Hora_Inicio.push(val.Hora_Inicio);
            Habitacion.push(val.Habitacion);


                        if (val.Hora_Inicio == hi && val.Habitacion == h) {
                        alert("La habitacion ya ha sido reservada a esa hora, seleccione otra hora");
                        return false;
                            }

                            if (val.Hora_Inicio !== hi && val.Habitacion !== h) {

                            if (i==data.length) {
                        recolectarDatos();
                        EnviarInfo('agregar', nuevoEven);
                            return false;
                            }

                        }
                        i++;

            })


            });//fin getJSON



    });     



    function recolectarDatos(){

            nuevoEven={
            title : $('#comboboxHabitacion').val(),
            descripcion : $('#txtFecha').val(),
            start : $('#txtFecha').val()+" "+$('#comboboxHora').val(),
            end : $('#txtFecha').val()+" "+$('#txtFechafinal').val()
            };  
            var texto =  "Se ha hecho la reserva el dia "+$('#txtFecha').val()+" de "+text+" a "+ $('#txtFechafinal').val();
            //document.getElementById("textToEncode").innerHTML = texto;
            alert(texto);
            }


            function EnviarInfo(accion, objetoEven){
                $.ajax({ 
                    type :'POST',
                    url : 'even.php?accion='+accion,
                    data : objetoEven,
                    success:function(msg){
                        if(msg){
                            $('#CalendarioReserva').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            $("#ventanaModal").modal('toggle');

                        }
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("Hay un error");
                    }
                })

            }

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

y mi even.php:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=habitaciones;host=127.0.0.1","root","");//Conexion a db

$Clien_User_ID = "Julina23";

$accion = (isset($_GET['accion']))?$_GET['accion']:'leer'; 
switch ($accion) {
    case 'agregar':     //accion para agregar a base de datos 
            $sentenciaSQL = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO reserva(Clien_User_ID,Habitacion,Fecha,Hora_Fin,Hora_Inicio)
                    VALUES(:Clien_User_ID,:Habitacion,:Fecha,:Hora_Fin,:Hora_Inicio)");
            $respuesta=$sentenciaSQL ->execute(array(
                "Clien_User_ID" => $Clien_User_ID,
                "Habitacion" => $_POST['title'],
                "Fecha" => $_POST['descripcion'],
                "Hora_Fin" => $_POST['end'],
                "Hora_Inicio" => $_POST['start']

                ));
            echo json_encode($respuesta);
        break;

    case 'fechainicio': 
            $sentenciaSQL= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM reserva WHERE Hora_Inicio");
            $sentenciaSQL->execute();
            $eventos = array();

            foreach($sentenciaSQL as $resultado){
            $Hora_Inicio = $resultado['Hora_Inicio'];
            $Habitacion= $resultado['Habitacion'];
            $eventos[] = array('Hora_Inicio' => $Hora_Inicio,'Habitacion' => $Habitacion); 
        }
            $arrayJson = json_encode($eventos, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); 
            print_r($arrayJson);
        break;

    default:    
            $sentenciaSQL= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM reserva");
            $sentenciaSQL->execute();

            $eventos = array();
            //pasa por un arreglo los datos recogidos de la db en la tabla reservas
            foreach($sentenciaSQL as $resultado){
            $title = $resultado['Habitacion'];
            $start = $resultado['Hora_Inicio'];
            $end = $resultado['Hora_Fin'];
            $eventos[] = array('title' => $title, 'start' => $start, 'end' => $end); 
        }

            $arrayJson = json_encode($eventos, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); //codifica a json
            print_r($arrayJson);
        break;
    }



?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con este codigo se podra lo unico que hago es crear la variable status y donde antes estaba el return ahora solo esta el status = true y por ultimo elimino dos if y el i++.

```
   $.getJSON('even.php?accion=fechainicio', function (data) { //getJSON
    var status = false;
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    Hora_Inicio.push(val.Hora_Inicio);
    Habitacion.push(val.Habitacion);


                if (val.Hora_Inicio == hi && val.Habitacion == h) {
                  status = true;
                }

    });

    if(status) {
      //Aqui el codigo cuando la reservacion este ocupada
    }else{
      //Aqui cuando este libre
    }

    });
```

Comment: en efecto me funciona al hacer el registro colocando el else, pero ahora si registro la misma habitación a la misma hora no me sale el mensaje de que ya había sido registrado, es decir omite el if y pasa al else, no comprendo el por qué

Comment: haber necesito todo el código del html o php.

Comment: Solo necesitaría como la lógica para poder continuar, pero igual ahí dejé todo lo que llevo

Comment: Eso debería funcionar revisa que todos los datos de el `$.each` sean correctos con un console.log(), por que eso por lógica funciona.

Comment: La lógica no está bien, porque si se da cuenta en la primera iteracion si no se repite la hora y la habitación ingresada, pasaría al else y de una ingresa un dato sin haber comprobado los demas y termina el ciclo ahi por el return false

Comment: te dejo la respuesta arriba.